# EC2 automatically adding DENY All Traffic rule in Network ACL (Unable to edit the rule)

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-ec2, acl, inbound-security-rule

My website (korrade.com) always shows up "Connection Timed Out" error, even though in my security group "Port 80" is shown open, and SSH works fine over Port 22(No Issues). I have only ALLOW rules in my security group.

Upon debugging, I found these Network ACL rules, out of which 1 seems strange as its getting automatically added by AWS.

[image: NACL rules]

I believe the inclusion of this rule is causing the website to not open. Or I think something else serious is there. As of now, this is the obs from my side..

1. I have Security Group configured, with only ALLOW rules
2. `/sbin/iptables -L` (showing nothing)
3. Telnet status of Port 80 says CLOSED
4. Firewall Status: not Loaded

Please help anyone... Much appreciated!

Post editing NACL & SG,

[Security Group Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx33G.jpg)

[SSH over WinSCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02dPK.jpg)

Comment: That's not a default ACL so you must have edited it (to add the #1 and #2 rule, and remove the default #100 ALLOW All traffic rule). Unless you need to use ACLs, don't use them. A security group is more than sufficient for most purposes.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5):

The `*` rule in a Network Access Control List (NACL) is a *catch-all* for any packets that do not meet any of the numbered rules.

The NACL in your picture will `Allow` any HTTP and SSH traffic. All other traffic will be Denied.

**Security Groups** default to **Deny all inbound traffic** and **Allow all outbound traffic**. You should then typically add rules to the Inbound traffic based upon the needs of your application and server.

**NACLs** default to **Allow all inbound & outbound traffic**. Traditionally, there is no need to edit a NACL because the Security Group is more appropriate. However, a NACL is **Stateless**, which means you need to specifically permit traffic **in both directions** -- inbound an outbound.

I would recommend:

- Unless you have a good reason, **reset your NACLs to default** (100, All traffic, Allow) for both Inbound and Outbound
- Try connecting to web server via its **Public IP address** rather than DNS Name (to test connectivity)

If problems persist, you can Edit your question to show your Security Group settings.

Comment: Hi John, As per your suggestion I did reset all my NACL's and SG's. Now only in my SG I have set up a rule to allow HTTP & SSH. But surprisingly its only allowing SSH connections, where as HTTP is still not open. I have edited the question and added a screen of my SG now. Even tried with All Traffic option, still no luck

Comment: Try logging into the instance via SSH then using `curl http://localhost` to confirm that your web server is running. If so, try connecting to the instance from your own computer by connecting to the **Public IP Address** of the instance (not its domain name). Could you please also include a picture of your Inbound Security Group that is associated with the instance.

Comment: Its says "0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused"... Here is the snap of Inbound Security Group https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx33G.jpg

Comment: If you login to to the instance itself and run `curl http://localhost` and it returns an error, it means means that the web server (or whatever web application) you are running on that server is not responding. It is *not* a network/security problem -- your application itself is not responding as a web server. Get whoever installed it to fix it.

Comment: Mine is a static website, with just an index.html file. I am not using any complex code or self configured Apache. Just one last thing, Could you suggest if the Amazon Key Pair/ Certificate which its tells to install in your directory could be causing an issue ? Its because I restarted my instance, and it gave me new IP sets altogether

Comment: Are you running a web server on the EC2 instance? If not, that explains your problem -- nothing is serving your web pages. If all you want is a static website, I would recommend using [Amazon S3 static website hosting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html).

Comment: Sure thanks, I guess with your help I am much closer to finding a solution now.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "closer to finding a solution"? If your intention is to serve web pages from that server, then your solution is to run a web server on the instance. If your goal is to have a static website, use Amazon S3 instead of Amazon EC2. It's cheaper and easier.